# ROS Service in C++ not being built

Tags: ros, services, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using ROS Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.
I am trying to write a c++ service to send some multi array data on request from the client  from server
I wrote the following code for that in c++

service definition file : RequestWaypoints.srv

```
---
int64multiarray waypoints
```

RequestWaypoints_server.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "visualize_waypoints/RequestWaypoints.h"

float waypoints[9][3] = {
              {-6.922, 12.437,-1.315},
              {3.067, -17.730, -1.315},
              {3.067, -17.730, -2.956},
              {-1.645, -19.531,-2.956},
              {-1.645, -19.531,1.892},
              {-12.163, 10.458,1.892},
              {-12.163, 10.458,0.351},
              {-6.922, 12.437,0.351},
              {-6.922, 12.437,-1.315}
            };


bool send_waypoints(visualize_waypoints::RequestWaypoints::Request  &req,
         visualize_waypoints::RequestWaypoints::Response &res)
{
  res.waypoints = waypoints;
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "RequestWaypoints_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("RequestWaypoints", send_waypoints);
  ROS_INFO("Waypoints were sent.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

RequestWaypoints_client.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "visualize_waypoints/RequestWaypoints.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "visualize_waypoints_client");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts>("add_two_ints");

  visualize_waypoints::RequestWaypoints srv;
  waypoints = client.call(srv)
  ROS_INFO("Received Waypoints are : %f", (float)srv.response.waypoints);
  return 0;
}
```

I added following lines of code in Package.xml

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

I added following code in cmakelist.txt file

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_service_files(
   FILES
   RequestWaypoints.srv
 )

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )
add_executable(RequestWaypoints_server src/scripts/RequestWaypoints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RequestWaypoints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(RequestWaypoints_server RequestWaypoints_gencpp)

add_executable(RequestWaypoints_client src/scripts/RequestWaypoints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RequestWaypoints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(RequestWaypoints_client RequestWaypoints_gencpp)
```

Once I run catkin_make I get following error

```
Base path: /home/rnd424/ros_ws
Source space: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Using CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES: visualize_waypoints
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - visualize_waypoints
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'visualize_waypoints'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(visualize_waypoints)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em:56: error: <class 'genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec'>: Invalid declaration: int64multiarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3302, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3300, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3283, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2295, in wrap
    self.fail(e)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2284, in wrap
    callable(*args)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2359, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2401, in safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2421, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 1425, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2595, in execute
    _exec(statements, self.globals, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 42, in _exec
    exec("""exec code in globals""")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 48, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/deps.py", line 70, in find_srv_dependencies_with_type
    spec = genmsg.msg_loader.load_srv_from_file(msg_context, msg_file, full_type_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 486, in load_srv_from_file
    spec = load_srv_from_string(msg_context, text, full_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 471, in load_srv_from_string
    msg_out = load_msg_from_string(msg_context, text_out.getvalue(), '%sResponse'%(full_name))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 266, in load_msg_from_string
    field_type, name = _load_field_line(orig_line, package_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 225, in _load_field_line
    raise InvalidMsgSpec("Invalid declaration: %s"%(orig_line))
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: Invalid declaration: int64multiarray
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python" "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/visualize_waypoints/cmake/visualize_waypoints-genmsg-context.py"
  "-o"
  "/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/visualize_waypoints/cmake/visualize_waypoints-genmsg.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em") returned error
  code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (em_expand)
  visualize_waypoints/CMakeLists.txt:76 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/rnd424/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:584: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Can you tell me what is the error and how to solve it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331828/ros-service-in-c++-not-being-built/) by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haresh Miriyala](https://answers.ros.org/users/39616/haresh-miriyala/) on 2020-06-24**:
having same issue here. the c++ source file is unable to include the ros service message :/

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-06-25**:
I guess there is an issue with either your includes, how you set up your dependencies or your service file. Please open a **new question** and provide the relevant details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The relevant error message is:

> Invalid declaration: int64multiarray

I.e., the service definition is wrong. It needs to be

```
---
Int64MultiArray waypoints
```

Note the case of the letters. This is case sensitive! See [the `std_msgs` type definition for `Int64MultiArray` for reference.](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int64MultiArray.html)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on 2019-08-28**:
Hi mgruhler,

I changed the imt64MultiAraay to int64[]
I get the following error

```
CMake Error at visualize_waypoints/CMakeLists.txt:159 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:
    src/RequestWaypoints_client.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx

CMake Error at visualize_waypoints/CMakeLists.txt:155 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:
    src/RequestWaypoints_server.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: RequestWaypoints_client
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "RequestWaypoints_client".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: RequestWaypoints_server
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "RequestWaypoints_server"
```

How to resolve this issue ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-28**:
This is another totally unrelated issue. You probably have specified a path in your `CMakeLists.txt` that doesn't exist. The error points to `src/RequestWaypoints_client/server.cpp, whereas the` CMakeLists.txt`you posted above had a (in my opinion unnecessary)`scripts` subdirectory between.

In general, for a specific question like the above, if this is solved, please mark the appropriate answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer and open a new question with any follow-up questions that don't relate directly to the first one.

If follow-up questions relate to the original issue, please edit your question instead of only commenting with follow-up stuff.